# Add Field Dependency in web-to-lead form

Tags: web2lead

I have added field dependency field in salesforce when ever i create a new web-to-lead form at that time filed dependency is not included them so how can i add in web-to-lead form?

Comment: Hi i have the same problem. Did you found any solutions?! thanks

Answer (score 1):

Web-to-lead only exposes a pure (and simple) HTML form. If you want any logic or dependancy between the fields or options, you'll have to add that yourself with javascript.

Just like you'd always have to update your web-to-lead form any time new fields or picklist values are added, you'll also have to update your javascript if dependancies are changed in salesforce.