# Dependent Fields in Web a lead form

Tags: html, web2lead, dependent-picklist

when i calling a dependent picklists in the model to web leads, 
addiction is not working. 
What syntax should I use ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What's addiction ?  Is this the same question as  : http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/68741/add-field-dependency-in-web-to-lead-form   ?

Comment: I think yes,  the dependency don't work.